# Content Query Web Part - Get each task's site

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part, xslt

Using a custom content query web part and XSL file in SharePoint 2016, I am bringing in tasks across a site collection. I would like to bring in each task's associated site. Using [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8fdecc1c-7999-49b1-af9e-e6ca9a212f35/cqwp-projectpropertyurl?forum=sharepointdevelopment) as a reference, I have added the following to my webpart file:

```
<property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string">
  <![CDATA[<ProjectProperty Name="Title" />]]>
</property>
```

and the following to my XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ProjectProperty.Title" />
```

This is still not bringing in the site titles.

What can I do to achieve this?